# What is the difference between 'time -f "%M"' and 'valgrind --tool=massif'?

Tags: memory, valgrind, massif

I want to see the peak memory usage of a `command`. I have a parametrized algorithm and I want to know when the program will crash due with an out of memory error on my machine (12GB RAM).

I tried:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%M" command
valgrind --tool=massif command
```

The first one gave me `1414168` (1.4GB; thank you [ks1322](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72178/ks1322) for pointing out it is measured in KB!) and valgrind gave me

```
$ ms_print massif.out
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 75 26,935,731,596       22,420,728       21,956,875       463,853            0
```

I'm a bit confused which number I should take, but let's assume "total" (22MB).

And the `massif-visualizer` shows me

[image]

Now I have 3 different numbers for the same command:

- `valgrind --tool=massif command` + `ms_print`: 22MB
- `valgrind --tool=massif command` + `massif-visualizer`: 206MB (this is what I see in `htop` and I guess this is what I'm interested in)
- `time -f "%M" command`: 1.4GB

Which is the number I should look at? Why are the numbers different at all?

Comment: Ah, so it is in KB? Interesting. But then I still wonder why the numbers are so different.

Comment: Yes, it is in KB. Does the `command` spawn any processes or threads? Try `valgrind --trace-children=yes`.

Comment: Are "heap" and "resident memory" the same ? Because as far as I understand massif measures "heap" whereas time measures "resident memory"

Comment: resident memory includes the heap, and also the stack.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/bin/time -f "%M"` measures the maximum RSS (resident set size), that is the memory used by the process that is in RAM and not swapped out. This memory includes the heap, the stack, the data segment, etc.

This measures the max RSS of the children processes (including grandchildren) taken individually (not the max of the sum of the RSS of the children).

`valgrind --tool=massif`, as the documentation says:

> measures only heap memory, i.e. memory allocated with malloc, calloc, realloc, memalign, new, new[], and a few other, similar functions. This means it does not directly measure memory allocated with lower-level system calls such as mmap, mremap, and brk

This measures only the memory in the child (not grandchildren).
This does not measure the stack nor the text and data segments.

(options likes `--pages-as-heap=yes` and `--stacks=yes` enable to measure more)

So in your case the differences are:

- `time` takes into account the grandchildren, while `valgrind` does not
- `time` does not measure the memory swapped out, while `valgrind` does
- `time` measures the stack and data segments, while `valgrind` does not

You should now:

- check if some children are responsible of the memory consumption
- try profiling with `valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes` to check the stack
- try profiling with `valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes` to check the rest of the memory usage

Comment: Thank you! (+50) - I will check this (probably next week) and might come back with questions (or directly accept the answer :-) )