# Which Valgrind tool and option to use for investigation of RAM allocation for each function?

Tags: r, linux, memory-leaks, julia, valgrind

I have never used `Valgrind`, but I think this tool can help me with my question. I would be grateful for any help.


In my `R` code, I use the `MixedModels` `Julia` package.

I integrate `Julia` in `R` using the `JuliaCall` package.

I work with very large datasets (~`1 GB`, ~`4x10^6` observations) and at the modeling step (`mixed models`) a lot of RAM is allocated (~`130 GB`), most of it does not return to the system after the end of calculations.


I would like to analyze the code and **see the whole stack of `R` and `Julia` functions**. 

It is very important for me to **understand what functions are called up during `mixed models` calculation with `Julia` (especially low-level functions, most likely written in `C / C ++`), and how much memory each of these functions utilize**.


It is also important to understand what exactly the memory is spent on, what exactly happens in the `RAM` when the functions from the `MixedModels` package are running.


 
Perhaps understanding this will help me improve the performance of the code and reduce the memory allocation.


Maybe for my tasks some other tool (rather than `Valgrind`) will be more useful - I will be very grateful for the relevant recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example of `valgrind --tool=massif`, using Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) (so no r or Julia related, but just as an illustration)

See [commit 51d1b69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51d1b69a534b591aa4afdc6f64c0e7aa8d886961) (26 Jul 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 068fa54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/068fa54c0034be0b953d798628b06815f9cfaff0), [commit 90b2bb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90b2bb710da47f12967a6f6a32640c197ca82685), [commit 5766524](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5766524956714d51b131d826a2894c85949e5770) (19 Jul 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit acbec18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acbec18d8e763069f55f895d15ebb37e9162357d), 03 Aug 2022)</sup>

The codepath to write [`multi-pack` index](https://github.blog/2022-08-29-gits-database-internals-i-packed-object-store/#packfiles-and-pack-indexes) ([introduced here](https://github.blog/2021-04-29-scaling-monorepo-maintenance/)) has been taught to release a large chunk of memory that holds an array of objects in the packs, as soon as it is done with the array, to reduce memory consumption.

> ### [`midx`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/068fa54c0034be0b953d798628b06815f9cfaff0): reduce memory pressure while writing bitmaps
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> We noticed that some '[`git multi-pack-index write`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/068fa54c0034be0b953d798628b06815f9cfaff0/Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt#L35)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-multi-pack-index#Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt-write))</sup> `--bitmap` processes were running with very high memory.
> It turns out that a lot of this memory is required to store a list of every object in the written multi-pack-index, with a second copy that has additional information used for the bitmap writing logic.
>
> Using '`valgrind --tool=massif`' before this change, the following chart shows how memory load increased and was maintained throughout the process:
>
> ```
> GB
> ^ 4.102                                                       ::
> |              @  @::@@::@@::::::::@::::::@@:#:::::::::::::@@:: :
> |         :::::@@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |      :::: :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |    :::: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |    : :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |    : :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |   :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |   :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |   :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |   :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |   :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |   :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> |   :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> | @ :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> | @ :: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> | @::: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> | @::: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> | @::: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> | @::: :: : :: @@:@: @ ::@ ::: ::::@: ::: @@:#:::::: :: : :@ :: :
> +--------------------------------------------------------------->
> ```
>
> It turns out that the 'struct `write_midx_context`' data is persisting through the life of the process, including the 'entries' array.
> This array is used last inside `find_commits_for_midx_bitmap()` within `write_midx_bitmap()`.
>
> If we free (and nullify) the array at that point, we can free a decent chunk of memory before the bitmap logic adds more to the memory footprint.
>
> Here is the massif memory load chart after this change:
>
> ```
> GB
> ^ 3.111#
> |      #                              :::::::::::@::::::::::::::@
> |      #        ::::::::::::::::::::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#  :::::::::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |     @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |  :::@#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |  :: @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |  :: @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> |  :: @#::: ::: :::::: :::: :: : :::::::: : :: : @:: ::::: :: ::@
> +--------------------------------------------------------------->
> ```
>
> The previous change introduced a refactoring of `write_midx_bitmap()` to make it more clear how much of the 'struct `write_midx_context`' instance is needed at different parts of the process.
> In addition, the following defensive programming measures were put in place:
>
> 1. Using `FREE_AND_NULL()` we will at least get a segfault from reading a `NULL` pointer instead of a use-after-free.
> 2. '`entries_nr`' is also set to zero to make any loop that would iterate over the entries be trivial.
> 3. Add significant comments in `write_midx_internal()` to add warnings for future authors who might accidentally add references to this cleared memory.

Note that `valgrind --tool=massif`, as the [documentation mentions][3 measures only heap memory, i.e. memory allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `memalign`, `new`, `new[]`, and a few other, similar functions.
This means it does not directly measure memory allocated with lower-level system calls such as `mmap`, `mremap`, and `brk`.

See more with "[What is the difference between '`time -f "%M"`' and '`valgrind --tool=massif`'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106135/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind contains several tools, two or three of which may be of use to you.

However, the first thing that you need to do is to reduce the size of your model. Valgrind has large time and memory overheads. Running Valgrind on an application that allocates 130Gb of memory is likely to be exceedingly slow. However, if you just scale down the size of your data, the insights that you get should still be valid.

The first tool to consider is `memcheck`. This is the most commonly used Valgrind tool. In addition to other types of error, it can detect memory leaks. Run

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes {your app} {your app arguments}
```

You need to examine the output to determine whether there are any leaks or whether memory is being held (possibly for later reuse).

The next tool to consider is `massif`. This is a heap memory profiler. It will generate a graph of how the memory use evolves over the duration of your application's execution. Run

```
valgrind --tool=massif {your app} {your app arguments}
```

This will generate a text file that you can either see with [massif visualizer](https://kde.org/applications/development/org.kde.massif-visualizer) (a kde5 graphical application) or with ms_print (part of the Valgrind distribution), a command line tool that will generate an ascii-art graph. Additionally, if you are using a relatively recent version of Valgrind you can use the xtree options with `massif` and will generate a text file that you can load in `kcachegrind` (another kde5 graphical application). This will give you a "tree" view of which calls allocate how much memory.

Lastly there is `DHAT` (`exp-dhat` if you are you are using an older version of Valgrind). This profiles the usage of heap memory. It will generate a text file that you can load from an html file that is part of the Valgrind distribution. (Or just a text file with older versions). Use `--tool=dhat` to use it. This tool can help track down memory that is either not really used or is used rarely and could possibly be released earlier in the program execution.

You may also want to look at other tools. For instance, Google perf tools has a `heapprofiler` component.

Comment: Thank you, Paul! 
I ran code with `memcheck` and the output did not show a memory leak. Then I launched the `massif` tool, but its output is too incomprehensible to me (I read it with `ms_print`). I also tried to run code with `xtree` option, but got an error like: valgrind: Unknown option: `--xtree-memory=full`

Comment: With `--tool=massif --xtree-memory=full`? If that is not working then your Valgrind is too old. You need 3.13 or later.

Comment: Yes, I have `valgrind-3.11.0`. Thank you, I'll upgrade to the latest version and try again.